# How to know the xdebug version I have installed?

Tags: xdebug

How to know the xdebug version I have installed?

Regards

Javi

Comment: phpinfo() perhaps? What OS are you running?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a simple test script:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

And get output like this:

[image: Screenshot of phpinfo output]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kHpWZ2G.png, thanks but please update the link

Answer (score 58):

`php -v` command output includes information about installed XDebug version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.13-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

or

```
$ php -v | grep -i "xdebug"
```

Comment: If working with php cli then `php -i` on the command line will also give you helpful information.

Answer (score 14):

I like using

```
php -r "var_dump(phpversion('xdebug'));"
```

from command line

Answer (score 11):

On Debian-based distros such as Ubuntu:

```
aptitude show php5-xdebug | grep Version
```

On Redhat-based distros such as CentOS:

```
yum info php-pecl-xdebug | grep Version
```

Answer (score 7):

From within PHP, use [`phpversion`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php):

```
$version = phpversion('xdebug'); // "2.5.5"
```

Xdebug uses PHP-standardized version string format, so you can use [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) on it:

```
if (version_compare('2.6.0.dev', $version, '<=')) {
    echo 'You are running at least the development version 2.6.0 of Xdebug';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[F.Y.I.] To detect whether xdebug is v3 or not by mashing up the @daniel and @bishop's answer.

```sh
php -r "exit(version_compare('3.0',phpversion('xdebug'),'>=')?1:0);"; echo $?
```

Useful for shell scripts in Dockerfiles and/or CIs.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# bash compatible
if php -r "exit(version_compare('3.0',phpversion('xdebug'),'>=')?1:0);"; then
    echo 'if xdebug3 then rewrite php.ini, downgrade, and etc.'
fi
```

I needed this since I got the below error while running PHPUnit.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error #2: Use of undefined constant XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED - assumed 'XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) on line 56 in file /workspaces/Sample/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/Driver/Xdebug.php in /workspaces/Sample/tests/TestCase.php on line 9
```

- Ref:

  - [Xdebug 3.0.0 is out!](https://xdebug.org/announcements/2020-11-25) @ xdebug.org
  - [Upgrading from Xdebug 2 to 3](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) @ xdebug.org